# Почему возникает «You don't have permission to access / on this server»?

Tags: ubuntu, apache

OS Ubuntu 16.04
Установила

```
> sudo apt-get install apache2
> sudo systemctl enable apache2
> sudo systemctl start apache2
```

Далее, мой файл находится в /etc/apache2/sites-available/it.loc.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName it.loc
ServerAlias www.it.loc
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /media/my_folder/3ABBCCD87BB08752/www/it.loc
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
<Directory /media/my_folder/3ABBCCD87BB08752/www/it.loc>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
  Require all granted
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Провела команды

```
sudo a2ensite it.loc.conf
 sudo systemctl restart apache2
sudo vi /etc/hosts
         127.0.0.1 it.loc
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```

и возникает такая ошибка. Апач у меня находится на компе, а папка сайта на внешнем жд. Почему такая ошибка?

Comment: Ну например, где-то в пути к `/media/my_folder/3ABBCCD87BB08752/www/it.loc` Апачу не хватает прав на чтение...

Comment: зашла на внешний диск, задала
sudo chmod 777 -R www/
не помогло

Comment: 0. за `chmod 777` пора ссылать в сибирь. 1. а в честь чего бы вам это могло помочь? 2. пользователю, от имени которого программа apache обслуживает ваш сайт, должны быть доступны для чтения и исполнения **все** каталоги по пути к `it.loc` (и он в том числе).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, спасибо за ответ. 
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 авг 29 12:34 media
drwxr-x---+ 4 root root 4096 авг 29 16:10 my_folder
drwxrwxrwx 1 my_folder my_folder  4096 авг 29 15:42 3ABBCCD87BB08752
drwxrwxrwx 1 my_folder my_folder          0 авг 29 16:37 www
drwxrwxrwx 1 my_folder taskgood 12288 авг 29 14:07 it.loc

Я добавила пользователя apache в группы 
 groups www-datawww-data : www-data root my_folder
толка ноль, вероятно из-за того, что группе root для папки не задан атрибут чтения

Comment: sudo chown -R www-data:www-data /media/my_folder/3ABBCCD87BB08752/www/it.loc
не помогло